# typescript Property 'type' does not exist on type 'never'

Tags: typescript

I have the typescript error `typescript Property 'type' does not exist on type 'never'` in the code

```
export const getSomething = (actionLog: [] | undefined) => {
  console.info(actionLog[length - 1].type)
}
```

What is the issue?

Comment: `[]` means "A tuple of length zero", which by definition has no elements and thus if indexed produces the type `never`

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to define type for 'type' property:

```
export const getSomething = (actionLog: {type: string}[] | undefined) => {
  console.info(actionLog[length - 1].type)
}
```

UPDATED:

```
export const getSomething = (actionLog: {type: string}[]) => {
  if (actionLog && actionLog[0]) {
    console.info(actionLog[length - 1].type)
  }
}
```

Comment: This code still wouldn't compile, at least under stricter settings, because `actionLog` might be undefined.

Comment: It compiles if you don't have `--strictNullChecks` enabled, but yeah this is still not great.

Comment: It will compile if you either a) wrap the `console.info` in an `if (actionLog)` to verify `actionLog` is defined, or b) use `!` to assert that `actionLog` is defined (`actionLog![length - 1]`).